# Hover effect issue in NSTableView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have a view based NSTableView in my application and I have added the hovering effect for the rows using the implementation in HoverTableDemo. I can get the hovering effect when the mouse is over a row without a problem , however when the tableview is scrolled down sometimes it leaves highlighting effect on the top cells when the table view is scrolled up again. I think this is due to NSTableView reuses the cell.  I highlight the row by overriding the

```
 - (void)drawBackgroundInRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
```

method in NSTableRowView. Could someone point me to the right direction to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Seeing the same problem here, just started to look into it. Did you get anywhere in the end (this question is two years old!).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the mouseExit event does not get called on scrolling and hence the background is not reset.